# Displaying Rails Required Fields Form Errors All At Once

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the Rails form and I'm also using Bootstrap tabs. I have 4 tabs that a user fills out and on the 4th tab is the submission button.  I have a number of `required: true` fields in the form, and when I go to click on the submit button leaving any of these fields blank, the pop-up saying "Please fill out this field" appears.

Question: How can I just have a box appear with ALL the error messages, instead of each individual error message appearing one at a time?

I've read a number of posts, and have tried most suggestions (with exception to ones that include JS, as I'm hoping there is a strong solution not including JS).  I put below some code below my submit button that I tried but it doesn't display anything as the individual box error message I think overrides it.

Any help is appreciated.

_Form:

```
<%= form_for(@property, html: { multipart: true }) do |p| %>
...

<%= p.file_field :picture, :multiple => true, name: "property_attachments[picture][]", size: 2 %>

<%= p.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% if @property.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@property.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @property.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out and learning a lot about Rails Forms.   I was using `required: true` for a number of fields and this created individual pop-ups on each error one by one.  I removed all of the `required: true` fields and then added validations in the model (eg. `validates: :price, presence: true`) and then the error message I used above in my question displayed any missing fields.